# Dúvidas sobre atualização dinâmica do dashboard no sistema

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

estou criando um sistema de gerenciamento de tarefas e tenho um dashboard que exibe as atualizações das atividades. O problema é que eu só consigo atualizar esse dashboard quando atualizo a página, pois estou exibindo as informações com uma consulta no MySQL com PHP.

Eu gostaria de quando eu atualizar o status de uma tarefa, ela seja atualizada em tempo real, no dashboard. Sem a necessidade do refresh na página.

Já pensei em diversas soluções com AJAX, e até fazendo alterações  visualmente no HTML para "enganar" o usuário até ele carregar a página. Mas está sendo muito trabalhoso e está me parecendo meio que gambiarra.

Vocês tem alguma solução pra mim ? Estou dependendo muito disso.

Veja abaixo a imagem do dashboard e da lista de tarefas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo, o código que uso para preencher o dashboard.

```html
<div class="row " id="row-resultados-dashboard">
    
    <div class=" col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0" id="resultados-dashboard">
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-pendentes">
      <p>Tarefas do mês</p>
      
      <?php
       while($linha_pendentes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_pendentes))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_pendentes['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
       
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-iniciados">
      <p>Fazendo</p>
      <?php
       while($linha_iniciados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_iniciados))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_iniciados['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
    
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-iniciados-vencidos">
      <p>Fazendo fora do prazo</p>
      <?php
       while($linha_iniciados_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_iniciados_vencidos))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_iniciados_vencidos['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
      
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-vencidos">
      <p>Fora do prazo</p>
      <?php
       while($linha_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_vencidos))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_vencidos['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
    
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover " id="resultados-concluidos">
      <p>Feito no mês</p>
      <?php
       while($linha_concluidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_concluidos))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_concluidos['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
      
     </div>
     
     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-concluidos-vencidos">
      <p>Feito fora do prazo</p>
      <?php
       while($linha_concluidos_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_concluidos_vencidos))
       {
      ?> 
       <h1> 
        <?php echo $linha_concluidos_vencidos['count(codigo)']; ?>
       </h1>

      <?php
       }
      ?>
      
     </div>
     
    </div>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualização sem refresh costumo usar Ajax com substituição de atributo val em campos em html em tags:

Para tal vamos criar uma pagina PHP que retorna os resultados em JSON:

**get_results.php:**

ps: eu não sei como esta sua tabela então me baseei só no seu código. Para melhorar esse tipo de pesquisa o ideal é que você execute um count com group by para retornar todas as contagens numa query unica evitando excesso de requisições ao banco:

```
<?php

//TAREFAS DO MÊS
while($linha_pendentes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_pendentes)){
    $mes = $linha_pendentes['count(codigo)'];
}

//Fazendo
while($lista_iniciados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_iniciados)){
    $iniciados = $linha_iniciados['count(codigo)'];
}

//Fazendo fora do prazo
while($linha_iniciados_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_iniciados_vencidos)){
    $fazendo_vencidos = $linha_iniciados_vencidos['count(codigo)'];
}

//Fora do prazo
while($linha_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_vencidos)){
    $vencidos = $linha_vencidos['count(codigo)'];
}

//Feito no mês
while($linha_concluidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_concluidos)){
    $ok_mes = $linha_concluidos['count(codigo)'];
}

//Feito fora do prazo
while($linha_concluidos_vencidos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista_concluidos_vencidos)){
    $ok_vencidos = $linha_concluidos_vencidos['count(codigo)'];
}

//Aqui construimos o retorno em json

$json_arr = array(
    'mes' => $mes,
    'iniciados' => $iniciados,
    'fazendo_vencidos' => $fazendo_vencidos,
    'vencidos'=> $vencidos,
    'ok_mes' => $ok_mes
    'ok_vencidos' => $ok_vencidos
);

//retornamos em formato json

echo json_encode($json_arr);
```

agora na sua página, temos que criar uma função para capturar esses dados e modificar seus cabeçalhos h1. Para isso, removi todo o php e adicionei identificadores nos seus "h1":

**index.php:**

```
<div class="row " id="row-resultados-dashboard">

<div class=" col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-0  col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-12 col-lg-offset-0" id="resultados-dashboard">

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-pendentes">
        <p>Tarefas do mês</p>

            <h1 id="mes">   
            </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-iniciados">
        <p>Fazendo</p>

            <h1 id="iniciados"> 
            </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-iniciados-vencidos">
        <p>Fazendo fora do prazo</p>

            <h1 id="fazendo_vencidos">  
            </h1>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-vencidos">
        <p>Fora do prazo</p>

            <h1 id="vencidos">  
            </h1>


    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover " id="resultados-concluidos">
        <p>Feito no mês</p>

            <h1 id="ok_mes">    
            </h1>


        ?>

    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4  col-lg-2 .relatorios dashboardhover" id="resultados-concluidos-vencidos">
        <p>Feito fora do prazo</p>

            <h1 id="ok_vencidos">   
            </h1>


    </div>

</div>
```

Ainda na sua index.php vamos adicionar uma função jQuery que vai executar a cada 15 segundos, atualizando os dados do dashboard:

```
<script>
    function update_dashboard(){

        $.ajax({

            url : "get_results.php", //pagina que retornará as contagens,
            type: "GET", // usaremos verbo GET pois não há necessidade de enviar dados
            dataType: "json", //retorno esperado em json
            success: function(object){

                //aqui atualizamos os seus H1 com os novos resultados:
                $("#mes").html(object.mes);
                $("#iniciados").html(object.iniciados);
                $("#fazendo_vencidos").html(object.fazendo_vencidos);
                $("#vencidos").html(object.vencidos);
                $("#ok_mes").html(object.ok_mes);
                $("#ok_vencidos").html(object.ok_vencidos);

            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("Erro ao atualizar");
            }

        });

    }

//para carregar os dados, executo a função ao carregar da página
update_dashboard();

//e aqui repitimos a cada 15 segundos pra não criar muitas requisições em menos de 1 min.
setInterval(function(){update_dashboard();}, 15*1000);


</script>
```

Comment: Will, sua sugestão foi válida. Porém a minha intenção seria que o dashboard fosse atualizado de acordo com a interação do usuário. Por exemplo: "Se ele alterasse o status de uma tarefa, o dashboard mudasse em tempo real".

Comment: ai você pode diminuir a quantidade de checagens na função... ao invés de 15 segundos, pode reduzir o tempo, checar de 1 em 1 segundo... mas não recomendo carregar o servidor de requisições assim. Talvez de 3 em 3 segundos... o caso é que você precisará deixar ele lendo algo pra ele saber quando deve se atualizar, seja um arquivo texto ou alguma coluna do banco...

Comment: Concordo, Will. Porém minha necessidade seria mesmo para atualizar só quando o usuário alterasse o status da tarefa. Não gostaria que uma função ficasse rolando no setInterval. Mas obrigado mesmo assim.

Comment: Will, se eu usar essa função de executar a cade 1 segundo, não irá gerar um processamento enorme no sistema ?

Comment: ... Mas mesmo assim sua resposta me foi muito útil, Will. Obrigado!

Comment: Thiago , se você colocar a cada 1s vai dar pico no servidor sim... ideal é que esse processo seja um pouco mais reduzido, eu geralmente dou um intervalo de 5 ou 10s

Comment: qlq coisa tamo as ordens